# Is there a possibility to bind the Form to a modal bootstrap window without using the load call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using ajax to make a request and open a modal bootstrap window afterwards. The problem is that when I use ajax, I make a request to my controller, and the return (modal content) I load as follows:

```
//modal loading
$('#contentModalFinanceiroParcela').html(data);

//exibição da modal
$('#modalFinanceiroParcela').modal({
    keyboard: true,
}, 'show');
```

So far, everything perfect. The problem is that from then on, I can't bind the form to register the submit event of the form. In the function bindFormFinanceiroParcela, no matter how much I pass the "dialog", bind does not work.

bindFormFinanceiroParcela(document.getElementById("contentModalFinanceiroParcela"));

Searching the forums, I found that the process works if I load the modal using the "load" command, as below, but I can't do it like that, otherwise it will make a second request to the controller, because previously, I already used ajax .

```
//That way it works, but I can't use it.
$('#contentModalFinanceiroParcela').load(url, function () {
    $('#modalFinanceiroParcela').modal({
        keyboard: true
    }, 'show');

    // Inscreve o evento submit
    bindFormFinanceiroParcela(this);

    stopLoadPage();
});
```

Is there a possibility that I can bind the form without using the "load" command mentioned in the script above?

```
    function openModalFinanceiroParcelaSemURL(data) {
    startLoadPage();

    //Create the modal window block in the body of the page
    if (!$("#modalFinanceiroParcela").data('bs.modal'))
        CreateModalFinanceiroParcela();

    //Load modal content via ajax request
    $('#contentModalFinanceiroParcela').html(data);

    $('#modalFinanceiroParcela').modal({
        keyboard: true,
    }, 'show');

   bindFormFinanceiroParcela(document.getElementById("contentModalFinanceiroParcela"));

   
    
    stopLoadPage();
}

function bindFormFinanceiroParcela(dialog) {
$('form', dialog).submit(function (e, i) {
    if ($(this).valid() || i) {
        startLoadOneMoment();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                     window.location = window.location;                       
                } else {
                    $('#contentModalFinanceiroParcela').html(result);
                    bindFormFinanceiroParcela();
                }
                stopLoadOneMoment();
            }
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

function CreateModalFinanceiroParcela() {
var html = '<div class="modal modal-primary modal-system" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalFinanceiroParcela" data-backdrop="static"><div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered"><div class="modal-content"><div class="content-modal-system" id="contentModalFinanceiroParcela"></div></div></div></div>';

$("body").append(html);
}
```

RAZOR DELETE:

```
@using Retaguarda.Domain.Enuns
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Financeiro.FinanceiroParcela.FinanceiroParcelaViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Excluir Parcela";
    Layout = null;
}
<div>
    <form asp-action="Delete" id="frm-excluir-financeiro-parcela">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="modal-shadow">
            <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4><i class="modal-title text-center glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> @ViewData["Title"] </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body  container-fluid pt-15 pl-15 pr-15">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <vc:summary />
                        <br />
                        <div class="message-delete">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new { id = "hid-financeiro-parcela-id" })
                            <i class="icon fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <p>
                                Tem certeza de que deseja excluir a parcela @(Model.Parcela)?<br />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm mr-auto"
                             role="group">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                                @*<button id="btn-excluir-financeiro-parcela" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon wb-check"></i> Excluir </button>*@
                                <button id="btn-excluir-financeiro-parcela" type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon wb-check"></i> Excluir </button>
                                <button id="btn-cancelar-financeiro-parcela" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon wb-close"></i> Cancelar </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Ajax call

```
$('#dtFinanceiroParcela').on('click', 'tr .btn-excluir-financeiro-parcela', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

startLoadOneMoment();

var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
var data = { id: id };
var dataURL = jQuery.param(data);

$.ajax({
    url: "/financeiro-parcela-gerenciar/remover-financeiro-parcela/" + id,
    type: "GET",
   // data: dataURL,
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
        if (typeof result.success !== 'undefined') {
            if (!result.success) {
                stopLoadOneMoment();

                swal("Oops", result.message, "error");

                return false;
            }
        }
       // alert(this.url);
        stopLoadOneMoment();
        openModalFinanceiroParcelaSemURL(result);
        
        return false;
    },
    error: function () {
        stopLoadOneMoment();
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz.

Comment: How does the html of the modal content look like?

Comment: Hi Martin Godzina ! updated the post :)

Comment: It seems like your form does not have any submit button due to the comment of the submit button @*<button ... type="submit" ... *@ Does your form contain a submit button when you inspect your html?

Comment: @Martin Godzina, Submit is being done via ajax, so it was removed from the button (this is not the problem he he). The problem is that the function bindFormFinanceiroParcela is not working when the modal is shown. It works if I load with jquery, but if I load contentModal like this: "$ ('# contentModalFinanceiroParcela'). Html (data)" the bindFormFinanceiroParcela function does not work.

Comment: how do you know it does not work?

Comment: actually the submit is not done with ajax in your code. With $(''...").submit(...) you attach an onSubmit event on your form. It may be true that inside your function you do a ajax call, but when no submit event is fired no ajax call will be called

Comment: @Martin Godzina, Forgive me, I forgot to post the so-called Ajax that carries the modal.

Comment: Every thing i can say is, that if your form does not contain a submit button the submit event will never be fired. It does not matter what you event callback contain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form inside razor does not contain any submit button because its commented out.

```
@*<button id="btn-excluir-financeiro-parcela" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon wb-check"></i> Excluir </button>*@
```

Remove the comment or change the type of the other button to "submit"

I guess the submit event is attached successfully but never called due to the missing submit button inside your form.